# Keep pixel perfect in every Android resolution with Cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, pixel

I'm making an Android game with pixel assets, they looks fine in my own phone but in some resolutions the assets seems stretched.
I've tested lots of things and searched a lot over the Internet but I can't get an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the bane of mobile development: playing with pixels.

The trick is to make sure you have your OpenGL camera set up to handle changes in aspect ratio and "pixel density" -- similar to what we used to call DPI.

Your game should be able to position the correctly-apportioned camera in a "letterbox" on the user's display. If you wish to expand out past that you may, but that is up to you.